# get data of id and include in update_batch in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a table shopping_cart which includes:

```
id | user_id | product_id | quantity | total_price
1    3         4            1         
2    3         5            2        
3    3         7            2
```

and products table include:

```
   product_ id | price |
    4            1000
    5            2000
    7            3000
```

this is my code for update_batch. there's a form with fields for id and quantity. I am planning to get the product price by id then multiply it by quantity then set the result to total_price . I searched for answers and they're all not working. how can I achieve this?

```
public function updateCart($data)
  {

    for($i=0;$i < count($data['id']);$i++)
    {
    
      $batch[] = array('id' => $data['id'][$i],
              'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i]
              );
    }

    $this->db->update_batch($this->table , $batch ,'id');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first fetch the product ID of the passed cart ID from the database, then use this product ID to fetch its price from the products table, then multiply the price with the quantity. The following should work:

```
public function updateCart($data)
  {

    for($i=0;$i < count($data['id']);$i++)
    {

      // select the product ID
      $this->db->select('product_id')->from('shopping_cart');
      $this->db->where('id',$data['id'][$id]);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $productID = $query->row_array()['product_id'];

      // now select the cost of the item from DB
      $this->db->where('id',$productID);
      $this->db->select('price')->from('products');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $productPrice = $query->row_array()['price'];

      // now calculate your total as:
      $total = $productPrice * $data['quantity'][$i];

      // and include it on the array as:
      $batch[] = array('id' => $data['id'][$i],
              'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i],'total_price' => $total
              );
    }

    $this->db->update_batch($this->table , $batch ,'id');
  }
```